# bootstrap 3 cannot set text input width inside div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set 3 different textfield width according to the wrapping div ( col-sm-3, col-sm-1, col-sm-2 ) , but they area ll the same width ..

```
                <div class="panel row">

                         <div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color: yellow;  padding: 0;">
                           <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                             <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Label</label>
                             <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-top: 4px;">
                                <input type="text" name="dynamic[1][]" value="1">
                             </div>
                           </div>
                         </div>

                         <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: grey; padding: 0">
                           <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                             <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Type</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-1" style="padding-top: 4px;">
                                <input type="text" name="dynamic[2][]" value="1">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                         </div>

                         <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: green; padding: 0">
                           <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                             <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Format</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top: 4px;">
                                <input type="text" name="dynamic[3][]"  value="1">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                         </div>

                </div>
```

Is there any simple way to have 2 textfields with these different widths ?

thanks for feedback

Comment: Could you explain your goal  with some more details? you mentioned 3 different sizes (as shown in code), but what do you mean by  "Is there any simple way to have 2 textfields with these different widths" ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap class **form-control** to inputs (example here http://www.bootply.com/mdTjf7rYks) or if you don't want to, just simply set width of inputs to 100% (example http://www.bootply.com/EXMQ9OJ7Jy)